# Variable uses an Automation type not supported in JScript

Tags: javascript, com, asp-classic, dcom

I have a simple asp page:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE = JScript %>

<%
    var app = new ActiveXObject("MyComponent");

    var out1 = { };
    var out2 = { };

   app.GetVersion(out1, out2);
%>
```

'MyComponent' is a DCOM object with the following definition:

```
interface IMyComponent : IDispatch
{ 
    HRESULT GetVersion([out, string] char**, [out] int*);
}
```

While executing GetVresion function I get error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Variable uses an Automation type not supported in JScript". 
How I can fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with "Out" Parameters in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122704/working-with-out-parameters-in-javascript)

Comment: Instead of `char **` try `BSTR *` for the string.