# calling COM method with Foo(..., [out] BSTR * value) from VBScript

Tags: com, vbscript, method-signature

Ist it possible to cal a COM method with the signature

```
 HRESULT Foo(BSTR in, [out] BSTR * out1, [out] BSTR * out2)
```

from VBScript?

The following:

```
 Dim a;
 Dim b;
 component.Foo "something", a, b
```

gives an error about incompatible types.

---

I still could change the signature of the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like output parameters are not supported; while `ByRef` / `[in, out]` parameters are, but only on `VARIANT` parameters.

From the following KB article:

[INFO: Type mismatch errors when you pass parameters from an ASP component to Visual Basic Component @ support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244012)

"*VBScript only supports VARIANT ByRef parameters. You can use VBScript to call a procedure that takes ByRef strings, but the default behavior of components built with Visual Basic is to fail with a type mismatch error when trying to pass ByRef parameters to these components. OLE Automation's default type-coercion function fails when asked to convert a ByRef variant into any other ByRef type.*"

Also, here are other links on the topic:

[In, Out, In-Out, Make up your mind Already @ MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/29/53117.aspx)
[VBScript “Type Mismatch” issue with “[in, out] BSTR * ” parameter SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241076)

Comment: Thanks, I've added a separate method with a "VBS-enabled" signature (`[ref] VARIANT *`)

Comment: @peterchen Could you, please, post the signature of the `COM` method and declaration of the `VARIANT` and the method call in `VBScript`. I can't seem to find a good example for the same problem.